# Recommended Reading on Regression Analysis?

Tags: statistics, reference-request, regression

For a university project, I am implementing an automated regression analysis tool.

However, I have very little background in statistics.

So what books / articles / material would you suggest I could use to brush up on this topic, based on your experiences?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Off the top of my head:

[Bevington *Data Reduction and Error Analysis for the Physical Sciences*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072472278)

[Draper, Smith *Applied Regression Analysis*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471170828)

[Chatterjee, Hadi *Regression Analysis by Example*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471746967)

[Belsley, Kuh, Welsch *Regression Diagnostics: Identifying Influential Data and Sources of Collinearity*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471691178)

[Monahan *Numerical Methods of Statistics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521791685) (not entirely about regression, but the chapter on regression has pointers on implementation)

I'm sure there are other nice refs, but I'll let the others point them out.

Comment: +1 for good refs and, if I could, another +1 for Belsley et al. (along with the implicit warning its inclusion conveys about mindlessly automated regression).

Comment: @whuber: Well, I have to credit Belsley *et al.* for making me less stupid about using regression analysis properly. :) Residual analysis saved my bacon at least twice...

Answer (score 5):

- Thisted, *Elements of Statistical
  Computing*
- Rao, *Linear Statistical
  Inference and Its Applications*
- Chapter 3 and 4 of Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman, *Elements of Statistical Learning* ([downloadable](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/))

Comment: Excellent link for Elements of Statistical Learning - thanks.