# Books on Function approximation and Regression

Tags: reference-request, regression, approximation-theory

Can you suggest books/articles on [Function approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_approximation)
Let me quote from the above wiki:

> Second, the target function, call it g, **may be unknown; instead of
>   an explicit formula, only a set of points of the form (x, g(x)) is
>   provided**. Depending on the structure of the domain and codomain of
>   g, several techniques for approximating g may be applicable. For
>   example, if g is an operation on the real numbers, techniques of
>   **interpolation, extrapolation, regression analysis**, and curve fitting can be used.

Any books/articles dealing with the above mentioned problem.Preferably with examples.

Comment: For regression, see [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10903).